# ¿Como utilizar windows.addEventListener en fresh web framework?

Tags: deno

Estoy realizando un portafolio con el framework web de deno llamado [Fresh](https://fresh.deno.dev/) y tengo problemas a utilizar los eventos de mi ventana, lo que quiero realizar es que el usuario al estar viendo la pagina se muestre un mensaje por defecto pero cuando deje de ver la ventana o pestaña cambie el mensaje, intenté utilizar el siguiente codigo:

```
window.addEventListener("blur", () => document.title = "¡No te vayas, regresa!")
```

El problema con el codigo anterior es que llamar `window` de esa manera salta un warning que dice lo siguiente

```
For compatibility between the Window context and the Web Workers, calling Web APIs via `window`
is disallowed\nInstead, call this API via `self`, `globalThis`, or no extra prefix
```

decidí seguir las recomendaciones del linter y cambié mi codigo de la siguiente manera

```
self.window.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    document.title = "¡Regresa por favor! ";
  });
```

he probado reemplazando `self` por `globalThis` y tampoco consigo resultados.

todo este código lo tengo dentro de un componente que estará en toda mi aplicación.

Comment: `globalThis` equivale a `window`, por lo que sería `globalThis.addEventListener`. Para tu caso creo que también sería válido `self.addEventListener`.

Comment: @HéctorM. Probé siguiendo tu recomendacion pero sigo sin resultados.

Answer (score 0):

El evento de `blur` se activa cuando un elemento ha perdido el foco, no cuando la *ventana* ha perdido el foco (ver [Window: blur event - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur_event)).

Se puede usar el evento de [`visibilitychange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event):

```js
addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
  document.title =
    document.visibilityState === "hidden"
      ? "¡Regresa por favor! "
      : "¡Gracias por regresar! ";
});
```